# CSS3 background gradient animation - background-size:cover not working?

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm pretty new to CSS3 animations so this is a tough one for me. I'm trying to create a kind of reflection effect on a topbar on my website to make users aware of the bar.

So I actually want a reflection wander from the left to the right of the bar rather quick and with easing.

I have two problems though …
1.) I have no idea why this thinkg won't work with `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:100% 100%`? It does just work when I specify a pixel width, however I just want it always to be 100% because the bar itself is always 100% wide.

2.) I have no idea how I could make the thing pause for like 3 seconds. So the reflection effect should start when the page is loaded, then pause for 3 seconds and then repeat.

Is this possible?

```
<div class="masked">
    <span class="inner">
    This is some Text
    </span>
</div>

background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(85,85,85,1) 0%,rgba(85,85,85,1) 48%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(85,85,85,1) 52%,rgba(85,85,85,1) 100%);
    background-size:1500px 20px;
    animation-name: masked-animation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/7Akwf/

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: divs inherently have no width or height. So 100% of 0 is, well, 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the animation to pause 3 seconds and continue you have to first set `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` and then use the `@keyframes` definition to control the delay by using a percent to be the pause.

In the demo below, I'm using `0%-50%` to be the full animation. Then I use `%50-%100` to be the pause.

If you want to use `background-size: 100% 100%;`, you need to set your `background-position: -2000px 0;` so it's totally off the left side of the screen if you want your animation to scroll by. You also need to adjust your `@keyframes` so it scrolls totally off the right side when done. Because of this extra distance, you'll need to adjust your duration accordingly to get the effect you're looking for.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jaRW3/

```
@keyframes masked-animation {
    0% {background-position: -2000px 0;}
    50% {background-position: 2000px 0;}
    100% {background-position: 2000px 0;}
}
```

Here I'm using a `6s` duration, of which `50%` will be the pause and `%50` will be the animation, or 3 seconds each. It also waits 3 seconds before starting. This uses the shorthand syntax which saves a lot of space.

```
animation: masked-animation 6s ease-in-out 3s infinite;
background-position: -2000px 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```